# Is it fine to use Ganache in a staging environment?

Tags: ganache

We are currently using Rinkeby in our staging environment, but planning to stop using it cause it doesn't make sense as our application will communicate with a private Ethereum network when it goes to production.

It seems that Ganache is the right tool to use, but after reading about it seems that people recommend using it as short lived environment only to run tests.

My question is: Is it fine to use Ganache as a long lived staging environment simulating a private ethereum network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ganache provides the following [Custom Methods](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#custom-methods), which a standard Ethereum node doesn't:

- `evm_snapshot`
- `evm_revert`
- `evm_increaseTime`
- `evm_mine`

If you avoid using those in your operational system, then you should be fine.

In addition to the above, Ganache allows you to maintain any number of accounts unlocked, so that you don't need to sign each transaction before sending it (i.e., you can use `send` instead of `signTransaction` followed by `sendSignedTransaction`).

This feature is also supported in standard ethereum nodes via `personal_unlockAccount`, but it is not a recommended mode of operation, since anyone hacking the node could exploit any of your unlocked accounts at will.

So you should probably avoid using the [accounts configuration](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#options-1) in your operational system.